# Trying read sql table, What's wrong in this?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, read-sql

It is not showing any output:

[image]

I was trying to read sql table using pandas in jupyter notebook which was there in my sql server database.I also install PyMySQL and sqlalchemy. It is neither showing an error nor the output table

Comment: The second parameter to read_sql_table() should be a connection, not an engine. Try con = engine.connect() and then df = pd.read_sql_table('Customers', con)

Comment: @DavidHarris. It works with an `Engine` instance (tested). However, what I don't understand is the DSN. Why is your mysql listening on port 80 and not 3306?

Comment: @Corralien Actually I don't know much about it, I watched a video and followed the instructions and i the tcp port in my mysql was 80.

Comment: How to check my host name and port number?

Comment: For a MySQL server the port is usually 3306, but where is your server running?

Comment: @Corralien Mysql workbench

Comment: Can you connect to your database with Mysql Workbench. Look at your "MySQL Connections"